# Can I execute Google Apps Script code from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I want to write a Chrome extension that allows users to send emails directly from the omnibox.  Is it possible to directly execute Google Apps Script code, such as the [Gmail Services API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/?hl=es-ES) from within a Chrome extension?

Comment: Did you get any solution for the above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can but with some limitation
If you publish your apps script code as a webapp which will be accessible publicly, you can make a GET request to the webapp URL to execute the Apps Script code.

e.g

```
doGet(e){
//use e.parameter here
//write your apps script code
return ContentService.createTextOutput('your return content');
}
```

after publishing it, say you got a URL like

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/djihwerd98ejdeijded/exec
```

Now make a request from your chrome app

```
GET https://script.google.com/macros/s/djihwerd98ejdeijded/exec?param=value
```

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work from a `chrome-extension` page?