# Write to a Google Doc from inside a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I want to create a Chrome extension that runs through a forum and copies all the links to each post on a particular page to a Google Spreadsheet.  I can't find much on using Google Apps Script in a Chrome Extension - does anyone have any resources or can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I execute Google Apps Script code from a Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404922/can-i-execute-google-apps-script-code-from-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely launch an Apps Script published as a web app from a chrome extension.  Here is a simple example. This extension will ask you to launch a script every time you open www.google.com. Annoying, but I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Background.js

```
// Handle requests for script launch
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.type === 'launch_script') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/YOUR SCRIPT URL/exec',
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
            // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                focused: true
                // incognito, top, left, ...
            });
        });
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Script Launch Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["open-dialog.js"]
  }]
}
```

open-dialog.js

```
if (confirm('Launch Script?'))
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'launch_script'});
```

Comment: this is not what is being asked. op wants to WRITE to a spreadsheet using apps script

Comment: If you can launch a webapp script, you can use the DocumentApp/SpreadsheetApp service.

Comment: thats not a good way to do it. one would use ajax with a content service, not opening a new tab with a webapp.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is yes, this is possible. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404922/can-i-execute-google-apps-script-code-from-a-chrome-extension) to a similar question includes a minimal working example.

However, given the [restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script#Limitations) [GAS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) [works under](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), I would instead consider skipping the Apps script part entirely, and instead using the [Sheets APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to access the content directly.